# How do I change the owner of a published Power BI App

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

An employee responsible for Power BI just quit at my workplace and he had created a couple of PowerBI apps that were later published organisation-wide.
I have no Power BI knowledge, and I've been tasked with transferring ownership of these apps since the ex-employee account is now set for deletion. I tried searching online but did not see anything that could help me.

Is there a guide somewhere that could help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to become the owner of the App Registrations for the Apps he created. You can do this through portal.azure.com if you search App Registrations then click the App(s) he created and there will be an "Owners" tab where you can remove him and add yourself.

Comment: When I look at App Registrations in Azure portal, I can't find any that have a similar name to the Power BI Apps. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Power BI apps are not displayed in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Only a Power BI administrator can access the workspaces from the ex-employee that the "apps" are built upon. From there you can "take over" the ownership.